# Can't set the data-href attribute of fb widget

Tags: jquery

I have a variable that changes depending on which host my webpage is running and I'm trying to dynamically set the `data-href` attribute of the fb share widget but I can't get it to be set to anything, it just remains unchanged.  This is the last thing I tried:

```
$( ".fb_iframe_widget" ).data( "href", CONFIG['domain'] );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.attr()` in order to set `data-*` value as shown :-

```
$( ".fb_iframe_widget" ).attr("data-href", CONFIG['domain']);
```

Comment: @JpajiRajnish..this should work..check your DOM, errors in console and `CONFIG['domain']`.

Comment: No errors in console.  But I just tried setting the `href` attribute and that doesn't work either, so it seems to not work for any attributes.  Maybe it has something to do with the facebook js sdk loading?

Comment: @JpajiRajnish..well may be...just check `CONFIG['domain']` by using a alert just above `$( ".fb_iframe_widget" ).attr("data-href", CONFIG['domain']);` line and see there must be a element `.fb_iframe_widget` inside DOM.

Comment: I found the problem, the `.fb_iframe_widget` was only getting added after the sdk loaded.  I tried the class that was hard coded and it now works.  Thanks for the help.